# Hide outlook 2016 icon from start menu using GPO or Script

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, windows-server-2012

I wanna Hide outlook 2016 icon from start menu of client users using GPO or Script.
I've tried to apply this policy "Remove All Programs list from the Start menu", but it hide all programs icons.
Any solution will be very helpful.

Comment: This question would be better suited to http://www.serverfault.com not stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the `.lnk` file, here's the PowerShell for that. Or if you are going the Group Policy method, then you could do this with a Preference.

```
Remove-Item "$env:ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Office 2016\Outlook 2016.lnk"
```